# odoo 8 ParseError: "ValidateError Field(s) `arch` failed against a constraint: Invalid view definition

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo

I'm trying to install a module in Odoo 8, and receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 537, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 574, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 310, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/model.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 307, in checked_call
    return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 803, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 403, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 952, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 940, in _call_kw
    return checked_call(request.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/model.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 939, in checked_call
    return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 447, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(cr, uid, ids, self.button_install, context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 495, in _button_immediate_function
    registry = openerp.modules.registry.RegistryManager.new(cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 370, in new
    openerp.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 355, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, update_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 255, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 176, in load_module_graph
    _load_data(cr, module_name, idref, mode, kind='data')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 118, in _load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, module_name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 901, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 987, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot(), mode=mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 853, in parse
    self._tags[rec.tag](self.cr, rec, n, mode=mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 763, in _tag_record
    id = self.pool['ir.model.data']._update(cr, self.uid, rec_model, self.module, res, rec_id or False, not self.isnoupdate(data_node), noupdate=self.isnoupdate(data_node), mode=self.mode, context=rec_context )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 1077, in _update
    res_id = model_obj.create(cr, uid, values, context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 255, in create
    context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 336, in old_api
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/models.py", line 4084, in create
    record = self.browse(self._create(old_vals))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 239, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 472, in new_api
    result = method(self._model, cr, uid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/models.py", line 4275, in _create
    recs._validate_fields(vals)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 239, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/models.py", line 1272, in _validate_fields
    raise ValidationError('\n'.join(errors))
ParseError: "ValidateError
Field(s) `arch` failed against a constraint: Invalid view definition

Error details:
Element '<xpath expr="/form/sheet/notebook/page[@string='General Properties']">' cannot be located in parent view

Error context:
View `Inherited Fleet Vehicle Form`
[view_id: 779, xml_id: n/a, model: fleet.vehicle, parent_id: 685]" while parsing /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/transport_sale-master/transport_sale.xml:125, near
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="inherited_fleet_vehicle_form_view">
            <field name="name">Inherited Fleet Vehicle Form</field>
            <field name="model">fleet.vehicle</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="fleet.fleet_vehicle_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <data><xpath expr="//label[@for='tag_ids']" position="before">
                      <label for="internal_number" class="oe_edit_only"/>                      
                    <h2>
                        <field name="internal_number" class="oe_inline"/>                                               
                    </h2>
                     <label for="is_trailer" class="oe_edit_only"/>                 
                     <field name="is_trailer" string="Is Trailer" help="Mark this if the vehicle is a trailer"/>
                </xpath>
                <xpath expr="/form/sheet/notebook/page[@string='General Properties']" position="after">
                    <page string="Transport sales">
                        <field name="sales_order_ids" readonly="1">
                            <tree editable="bottom">
                                <field name="sale_order_id"/>
                                <field name="sales_date"/>
                                <field name="partner_departure_id"/>
                                <field name="partner_destination_id"/>
                                <field name="delivery_date"/>
                                <field name="return_date"/>
                            </tree>
                        </field>
                    </page>
                </xpath>
            </data></field>
        </record>
```

According to the error the offending part of the module seems to be:

```
 <!-- Fleet vehicle sales form -->
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="inherited_fleet_vehicle_form_view">
  <field name="name">Inherited Fleet Vehicle Form</field>
  <field name="model">fleet.vehicle</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="fleet.fleet_vehicle_form" />
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="//label[@for='tag_ids']" position="before">
      <label for="internal_number" class="oe_edit_only"/>
      <h2>
        <field name="internal_number" class="oe_inline" />
      </h2>
      <label for="is_trailer" class="oe_edit_only"/>
      <field name="is_trailer" string="Is Trailer" help="Mark this if the vehicle is a trailer"/>
    </xpath>
    <xpath expr="/form/sheet/notebook/page[@string='General Properties']" position="after">
      <page string="Transport sales">
        <field name="sales_order_ids" readonly="1">
          <tree editable="bottom">
            <field name="sale_order_id" />
            <field name="sales_date" />
            <field name="partner_departure_id" />
            <field name="partner_destination_id" />
            <field name="delivery_date" />
            <field name="return_date" />
          </tree>
        </field>
      </page>
    </xpath>
  </field>
</record>
```

Found posts about plenty of similar errors with varying solutions which all seem to differ but none seem to work for me. What should I do?

**Edit**

Cleaned up first code block and replaced with full error in the second
after applying

```
<xpath expr="/form/sheet/group[@string='General Properties']" position="after">
```

as suggested in the comment below, my error is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 537, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 574, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 310, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/model.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 307, in checked_call
    return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 803, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 403, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 952, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 940, in _call_kw
    return checked_call(request.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/model.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 939, in checked_call
    return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 447, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(cr, uid, ids, self.button_install, context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 495, in _button_immediate_function
    registry = openerp.modules.registry.RegistryManager.new(cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 370, in new
    openerp.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 355, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, update_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 255, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 176, in load_module_graph
    _load_data(cr, module_name, idref, mode, kind='data')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 118, in _load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, module_name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 901, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 987, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot(), mode=mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 853, in parse
    self._tags[rec.tag](self.cr, rec, n, mode=mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 763, in _tag_record
    id = self.pool['ir.model.data']._update(cr, self.uid, rec_model, self.module, res, rec_id or False, not self.isnoupdate(data_node), noupdate=self.isnoupdate(data_node), mode=self.mode, context=rec_context )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 1077, in _update
    res_id = model_obj.create(cr, uid, values, context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 255, in create
    context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 336, in old_api
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/models.py", line 4084, in create
    record = self.browse(self._create(old_vals))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 239, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 472, in new_api
    result = method(self._model, cr, uid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/models.py", line 4275, in _create
    recs._validate_fields(vals)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 239, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/models.py", line 1272, in _validate_fields
    raise ValidationError('\n'.join(errors))
ParseError: "ValidateError
Field(s) `arch` failed against a constraint: Invalid view definition" while parsing /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/transport_sale-master/transport_sale.xml:125, near
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="inherited_fleet_vehicle_form_view">
            <field name="name">Inherited Fleet Vehicle Form</field>
            <field name="model">fleet.vehicle</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="fleet.fleet_vehicle_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <data><xpath expr="//label[@for='tag_ids']" position="before">
                      <label for="internal_number" class="oe_edit_only"/>                      
                    <h2>
                        <field name="internal_number" class="oe_inline"/>       
                    </h2>
                     <label for="is_trailer" class="oe_edit_only"/>                 
                     <field name="is_trailer" string="Is Trailer" help="Mark this if the vehicle is a trailer"/>
                </xpath>
                <xpath expr="/form/sheet/group[@string='General Properties']" position="after">
                    <page string="Transport sales">
                        <field name="sales_order_ids" readonly="1">
                            <tree editable="bottom">
                                <field name="sale_order_id"/>
                                <field name="sales_date"/>
                                <field name="partner_departure_id"/>
                                <field name="partner_destination_id"/>
                                <field name="delivery_date"/>
                                <field name="return_date"/>
                            </tree>
                        </field>
                    </page>
                </xpath>
            </data></field>
        </record>
```

**Edit**

after replacing [@string] for [@name] as suggested the error remains as follows below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 537, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 574, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 310, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/model.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 307, in checked_call
    return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 803, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 403, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 952, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 940, in _call_kw
    return checked_call(request.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/model.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 939, in checked_call
    return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 447, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(cr, uid, ids, self.button_install, context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 495, in _button_immediate_function
    registry = openerp.modules.registry.RegistryManager.new(cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 370, in new
    openerp.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 355, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, update_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 255, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 176, in load_module_graph
    _load_data(cr, module_name, idref, mode, kind='data')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 118, in _load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, module_name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 901, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 987, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot(), mode=mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 853, in parse
    self._tags[rec.tag](self.cr, rec, n, mode=mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 763, in _tag_record
    id = self.pool['ir.model.data']._update(cr, self.uid, rec_model, self.module, res, rec_id or False, not self.isnoupdate(data_node), noupdate=self.isnoupdate(data_node), mode=self.mode, context=rec_context )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 1077, in _update
    res_id = model_obj.create(cr, uid, values, context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 255, in create
    context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 336, in old_api
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/models.py", line 4084, in create
    record = self.browse(self._create(old_vals))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 239, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 472, in new_api
    result = method(self._model, cr, uid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/models.py", line 4275, in _create
    recs._validate_fields(vals)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 239, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/models.py", line 1272, in _validate_fields
    raise ValidationError('\n'.join(errors))
ParseError: "ValidateError
Field(s) `arch` failed against a constraint: Invalid view definition

Error details:
Element '<xpath expr="/form/sheet/notebook/page[@name='General Properties']">' cannot be located in parent view

Error context:
View `Inherited Fleet Vehicle Form`
[view_id: 866, xml_id: n/a, model: fleet.vehicle, parent_id: 830]" while parsing /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/transport_sale-master/transport_sale.xml:125, near
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="inherited_fleet_vehicle_form_view">
            <field name="name">Inherited Fleet Vehicle Form</field>
            <field name="model">fleet.vehicle</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="fleet.fleet_vehicle_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <data><xpath expr="//label[@for='tag_ids']" position="before">
                      <label for="internal_number" class="oe_edit_only"/>                      
                    <h2>
                        <field name="internal_number" class="oe_inline"/>                                               
                    </h2>
                     <label for="is_trailer" class="oe_edit_only"/>                 
                     <field name="is_trailer" string="Is Trailer" help="Mark this if the vehicle is a trailer"/>
                </xpath>
                <xpath expr="/form/sheet/notebook/page[@name='General Properties']" position="after">
                    <page string="Transport sales">
                        <field name="sales_order_ids" readonly="1">
                            <tree editable="bottom">
                                <field name="sale_order_id"/>
                                <field name="sales_date"/>
                                <field name="partner_departure_id"/>
                                <field name="partner_destination_id"/>
                                <field name="delivery_date"/>
                                <field name="return_date"/>
                            </tree>
                        </field>
                    </page>
                </xpath>
            </data></field>
        </record>
```

Running out of space here ;) EDIT is posted below

Comment: Hello please edit this line  ""<xpath expr="/form/sheet/group[@string='General Properties']" position="after">
                    position="after"&gt"" Why you are adding "&gt".? You should close the tag. Please start learning Odoo Documentation from starting before get dive into code directly. see here odoo.com/documentation

Comment: Hello, the problem is you defined `position` attribute 2-times.... As per your edited code...  remove `position="after"&gt;` from your code that you defined exactly after the xpath(that i suggest in the answer).

Comment: the "position="after"&gt" was a result of a pasting error

Comment: And the error still remains as is

Answer (score 1):

Error shows that the path you defined is not found in parent view(`fleet_vehicle_form`).

You need to correct that xpath.

As you using `Odoo- v8.0`,

`<xpath expr="/form/sheet/notebook/page[@string='General Properties']" position="after">`

change this xpath with the below one...

`<xpath expr="/form/sheet/group[@string='General Properties']" position="after">`

There is no `notebook & page` tags in parent view(`fleet_vehicle_form`). So, that's why it gives you error.

Comment: thnx, have tried changing the xpath before, but that still leaves me with an error:  'Field(s) `arch` failed against a constraint: Invalid view definition" while parsing /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/transport_sale-master/transport_sale.xml:125, near
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="inherited_fleet_vehicle_form_view">'

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here, am barely trying to grasp the python concept ;) You mean the ones i tried before?

Comment: ok.. Are you still facing the error after changing the xpath as define in the answer...??? Is it solved or not...!!

Comment: yes, still there, just not exactly the same error though, tried posting the error in my first comment, will edit my post with full 'code' of the error after applying your fix

Answer (score 0):

**View inheritance**

Instead of modifying existing views in place (by overwriting them), Odoo provides view inheritance where children "extension" views are applied on top of root views, and can add or remove content from their parent.

An extension view references its parent using the inherit_id field.

**Tip**

When matching a single element, the position attribute can be set directly on the element to be found. Both inheritances below will give the same result.

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='field_name']" position="after">
    <field name="new_field" />
</xpath>

<field name="field_name" position="after">
    <field name="new_field" />
</field>
```

Page can not be appended after group, you need to put it in side sheet or after/before any other page.

```
<xpath expr="/form/sheet/group[@string='General Properties']" position="after">
```

Update this line to

```
<page string="existing page string" position="after">
    <!-- add your page here -->
</page>
```

Very important thing in view inheritance is **PRIORITY**, but seems mostly ignored.

```
<field name="priority" eval="50" />
```

Priority defines when your view are going to be executed for creation while there are parent child hierarchies available.

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="inherited_fleet_vehicle_form_view">
    <field name="name">Inherited Fleet Vehicle Form</field>
    <field name="model">fleet.vehicle</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="fleet.fleet_vehicle_form"/>
    <field name="priority" eval="50" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//label[@for='tag_ids']" position="before">
              <label for="internal_number" class="oe_edit_only"/>                      
            <h2>
                <field name="internal_number" class="oe_inline"/>       
            </h2>
             <label for="is_trailer" class="oe_edit_only"/>                 
             <field name="is_trailer" string="Is Trailer" help="Mark this if the vehicle is a trailer"/>
        </xpath>
        <sheet position="inside">
            <page string="Transport sales">
                <field name="sales_order_ids" readonly="1">
                    <tree editable="bottom">
                        <field name="sale_order_id"/>
                        <field name="sales_date"/>
                        <field name="partner_departure_id"/>
                        <field name="partner_destination_id"/>
                        <field name="delivery_date"/>
                        <field name="return_date"/>
                    </tree>
                </field>
            </page>
        </sheet>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: Thanks, sounds like usefull information, however the error still remains as posted in 4thEDIT

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error "Field(s) `arch` failed against a constraint: Invalid view definition", I was using field from another module which needs to be listed in the 'depends' in **openerp**.py file. hope this helps.